# What is VPS\example.com_web identity in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, logins

I was facing `connection failed for requested login` in SQL server 2016 used for **example.com** domain on a VPS. I added the following logins to the database `NT AUTHORITY\IUSR` and `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` and `IIS AppPool\SampleAppPool` but the login failed untill I added the `VPS\EXAMPLE.COM_WEB` (found from the advanced search) and login was successful.

What is the identity of EXAMPLE.COM_WEB? It is not a windows user, nor application pool nor ISUR and SERVICES. I have to mention that there is **SolidCP** installed on the server. I don't know if these kind of identity is related to the solidCP and why it is needed to connect to database?

Answer (score 1):

This would be either a user generated and used in your application, or an AD group a user in your application is a part of, or a special AD group your application is reliant on while running in IIS. It has nothing directly to do with SQL Server. You may be able to find better information out on [ServerFault.com](https://serverfault.com/) or possibly [StackOverflow.com](https://StackOverflow.com).